# Rails 5: JS treeview from hash of dates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

I have model where distinct dates are found and then values are grouped by year, month, day:

```
def self.tree
  dates = MyModel.order("date_trunc('day', datetime_column) DESC")
           .distinct.pluck("date_trunc('day', datetime_column)")
  hash = Hash.new { |h, y| h[y] = Hash.new { |h2, m| h2[m] = {} } }
  dates_by_ymd = dates.each_with_object(hash) do |date, h|
    h[date.year][date.strftime('%B')][date.strftime('%b %d')] = date
  end
end
```

which prints out in view this hash:

```
{2016=>{"November"=>{"Nov 20"=>Sun, 20 Nov 2016 05:20:00 UTC +00:00}, "December"=>{"Dec 12"=>Mon, 12 Dec 2016 04:05:00 UTC +00:00, "Dec 24"=>Sat, 24 Dec 2016 18:51:33 UTC +00:00, "Dec 30"=>Fri, 30 Dec 2016 06:20:00 UTC +00:00}}, 2017=>{"December"=>{"Dec 12"=>Tue, 12 Dec 2017 15:15:00 UTC +00:00}}}
```

In controller I have this:

```
def update_placements
  @placements = #code which finds placements
  @treeview = @placements.tree
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**How do I turn hash above into some nice javascript treeview?** For [example like here](https://www.jstree.com/demo/):
[image]

I'd appreciate any hint where I should be looking at. Thank you!

**Addition**

In addition I'd need to be able to get records for particular day. Basically it would be opening year, month, day and then populating records for particular day. I was thinking to load year, month, day all together and then for each day records would be loaded separately since table could grow quite big. Records for day would be found buy `datetime_column`.

**Update**

In view have this code which populates treeview:

```
<div id="tree">
    <script>
       $('#tree').jstree({
           'core' : {
               'data' : [ <%= raw @treeview %> ]
              }
          });
    </script>
</div>
```

**How do I make years (in my example below 2017, 2016) as root nodes, please?** I'd like to get rid of "root".

[image]

JS with `data` like this:

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : [ { 'text' : 'Child 1' }, 'Child 2' ]
         }
});
```

would get rid of "node" like this:

[image]

and in "Child 1", "Child 2"... I would need to populate my 2016, 2017, etc. "text" in JS above is what you have "data" in your code.

Comment: Do you know how the JSON should look like?

Comment: @EricDuminil Here are examples - https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/  I was thinking simplest JSON version would be OK as there is not much data to load (few thousand items).

Comment: @EricDuminil Regarding tree population, in the end I will need to be able to load records related to particular day (I'd do separate query for that). It might be that [AJAX option from here](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/) is they way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have `dates_ymd` :

```
{2017=>
  {1=>
    {8=>#<Date: 2017-01-08 ((2457762j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
     3=>#<Date: 2017-01-03 ((2457757j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}},
 2015=>
  {12=>{5=>#<Date: 2015-12-05 ((2457362j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>},
   11=>{7=>#<Date: 2015-11-07 ((2457334j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}}}
```

You can use this method :

```
def to_js_tree(hash = tree, node = :root)
  hash.each_with_object({data: node}){|(k,v), new_hash|
    new_hash[:children] ||= []
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      new_hash[:children] << to_js_tree(v,k)
    else
      new_hash[:children] << {data: k, :children => [{data: v}]}
    end
  }
end
```

Example :

```
pp to_js_tree(dates_by_ymd)
# =>
{:data=>:root,
 :children=>
  [{:data=>2017,
    :children=>
     [{:data=>1,
       :children=>
        [{:data=>8,
          :children=>
           [{:data=>#<Date: 2017-01-08 ((2457762j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}]},
         {:data=>3,
          :children=>
           [{:data=>#<Date: 2017-01-03 ((2457757j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}]}]}]},
   {:data=>2015,
    :children=>
     [{:data=>12,
       :children=>
        [{:data=>5,
          :children=>
           [{:data=>#<Date: 2015-12-05 ((2457362j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}]}]},
      {:data=>11,
       :children=>
        [{:data=>7,
          :children=>
           [{:data=>
              #<Date: 2015-11-07 ((2457334j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}]}]}]}]}
```

and

```
puts to_js_tree(dates_by_ymd).to_json
#=> {"data":"root","children":[{"data":2017,"children":[{"data":1,"children":[{"data":8,"children":[{"data":"2017-01-08"}]},{"data":3,"children":[{"data":"2017-01-03"}]}]}]},{"data":2015,"children":[{"data":12,"children":[{"data":5,"children":[{"data":"2015-12-05"}]}]},{"data":11,"children":[{"data":7,"children":[{"data":"2015-11-07"}]}]}]}]}
```

In your case, you could just call :

```
@placements.to_js_tree.to_json
```

if you have defined

```
def self.to_js_tree(hash = tree, node = :root)
```

in your Placement Model.

## Update

If you don't want a root node with years as children, but an array with multiple trees and years as roots, you can add a new `to_js_trees` method :

```
def to_js_trees(hash = tree)
  hash.map{|year, year_tree|
    to_js_tree(year_tree, year)
  }
end
```

Note : `@treeview` is already an Array now, so you can just use `'data' :  <%= raw @treeview %>` instead of `'data' : [ <%= raw @treeview %> ]`

Comment: Thank you! I've put the method in Model, then in Controller `puts @placements.to_js_tree(dates_by_ymd).to_json` but it gives me error `undefined local variable or method `dates_by_ymd'` What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: Works like charm :)

Comment: Can you check my update above, please? I'd like to make populated years in treeview as rootes, but don't know how.

Comment: I don't know. Can a jstree have multiple roots? You'd need multiple jstrees with years as root. I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, it can. Please, see my JS code update above. Sorry, I did not check it earlier.

Comment: Thank you! I added `def self.to_js_trees(hash = tree)` method in model and changed in controller to this `@treeview = @placements.to_js_trees.to_json` however in view it produces single root node with any data, nor text. What could be wrong? I left `def self.to_js_tree(hash = tree, node = :root)` as it was since I need that `children` part to be done. Couldn't it be there is some conflict between those two model methods?

Comment: With `'data' :  <%= raw @treeview %>` it works :) Thank you so much!